# No mechanism for withdrawing an erroneously flagged post

Tags: discussion

I flagged a (closed) question, [What does the LED blinking on Arduino boot mean? [closed]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25267/what-does-the-led-blinking-on-arduino-boot-mean), for migration to the Arduino SE site.

Then to my horror, and embarrassment, I realised almost immediately, that I had already flagged the same question, for the exact same reason, back in July.

[image: Reflagged question]

Unfortunately, there is no UI element, or mechanism, for withdrawing a flag.

So:

1. I am going to look, at best, like a fool for flagging it twice, and at worse, annoy a moderator, who will (incorrectly) think that I am being persistent, and disagreeing with their original decision.
2. Will there be any punitive action taken again me, i.e. having my flags removed, or some black mark put on "my record"..?

This was an honest mistake.

Comment: As Dave said a few declined ones doesn't matter, if you're interested in how the automatic flag bans work the limits are documented here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405

Comment: @PeterJ - Thanks for the link

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about it.

But keep in mind that old questions can't be migrated — the system prevents it. And migrating a closed question requires reopening it first — if it was a bad question on this site, why wouldn't it be a bad question on the destination site, too? Make sure that a question you flag for migration would actually meet the criteria for the destination site — and isn't a duplicate of a question that's already there.

If the OP is still around, it would be better to simply suggest that he re-ask his question on the other site. If he isn't, it's pretty much of a moot point anyway.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I wasn't aware that old questions can not be migrated. I shall bear it in mind, henceforth.